# Wordpressから送信されるメールの「Date」ヘッダの日時について

Tags: wordpress

お世話になります。
Wordpressからメールを送信すると、「Date」ヘッダの値がUTCでの時間になってしまい、困っています。
例えば、

```
Date: Fri, 13 Sep 2019 20:26:37 +0900
```

となってほしいのですが、

```
Date: Fri, 13 Sep 2019 11:26:37 +0000
```

となってしまいます。
Wordpressの一般設定では、タイムゾーンとして「東京」を指定しています。
また、PHPの設定でも「date.timezone」は「Asia/Tokyo」が指定されています。
ちなみに、[WordPressの送信メールが協定世界時（UTC・グリニッジ標準時）の問題対応](https://blog.s-giken.net/260.html) というページを参考に「wp-settings.php」の

```
date_default_timezone_set( 'UTC' );
```

を

```
date_default_timezone_set( 'JTC' );
```

に変更してみましたが、そうすると、メールのDateヘッダの値は正常になるものの、サイトの時間が9時間ずれてしまいます。
何かよい対処法はありますでしょうか。
以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: OS自体のTimezoneでJapan/Tokyoが設定されてないのかもしれません。サーバー環境がわからないのですが、SSHでログインして`date`コマンドを打つことはできますか？

Comment: 「date」コマンドでは、「2019年  9月 15日 日曜日 15:06:49 JST」と表示されました。